# Joint graphs in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I want to make a graph similar to the one in the image. How do I make such a combined graph with 3 graphs stacked up vertically?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to SO! What have you tried so far? Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Did you try out `multiplot`?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service! Please show your own research effort. If you show your (not necessarily working) code and graph and tell where you are stuck, people will be willing to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A basic google search will provide you the answer. Since you haven't done that, here's a small example case

```
f(x) = abs(x)<2*pi ? a*sin(x)           : 1/0
g(x) = abs(x)<2*pi ? a*sin(x+pi/2)      : 1/0
set multiplot layout 2,1 rowsfirst
set label 1 'a' at graph 0.92,0.9 font ',8'
plot f(x) with lines ls 1
set label 1 'b' at graph 0.92,0.9 font ',8'
plot g(x) with lines ls 1
unset multiplot
```

The desired output:

[image]